# Simple documentation frameworks on android (like local HTML help)

Tags: html, documentation

I´m facing the challenge to transfer a long-grown (local) HTML documentation to Android.

As you probably know, all Android web browsers refuse the usage of local links inside the Android file system for security reasons. As the documentation will be used in field work, the upload to a web server is not an option. Even the experiments with local web servers on Android were unsatisfying. They are either unstable (due to the internal handling as a standard user app), lead to peculiar issues in the presention in browser and do not support links to HTML sites in folders, other than the site you are coming from.

Do you have any recommendations for the rebuilding of a local linked documentation? Is there any simple generic framework or app to accomplish this task? The writing, linking and management of the help documents should likely be done in Windows like before. I still did some research on this topic, but I couldn´t find any satisfying solution.

Comment: What you could potentially do is create a small web server and wifi hotspot on something like a Raspberry Pi, then bring that with you and connect to it to read the documentation.

Comment: Technically it is possible to create an app that displays HTML files from a local folder (e.g. `/sdcard/Andorid/<app packagename>/` but I don't know an existing app that could do so. If you have some Java skills you might be able to develop a simply app that only consists of a WebView showing your html files. https://stackoverflow.com/q/35699674/150978 would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your ideas!

In the end, I see the solution in using Markdown in combination with the edit/viewer app Joplin. It´s possible to arrange and link the different *.md documents like the HTML-Files before (and even use them on Windows). In case of complex formatting, I´ll use links to PDF documents.